# Hibernate.initialize exception - Cutting dependency chain

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I have a Class `A` which has an object of Class `B` which has an object of Class `C`. I want to get object of class `B` from object of class `A` without getting object of class `C` in b. (I have , and want to keep it this way, everything with lazy loading)

I am doing:

```
Hibernate.initialize(a.getObjectOfClassB());
```

But get exception. Is there any way to do what i want? Cutting the hibernate initialize chain?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Are you asking to obtain a List<B> that are not associated to neither A nor C?

Comment: no, i am asking to get the  List<B> that my object of class A has,  without bringing from data base the  List<C> that every object from List<B> has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your entity structures appear to be mapped as follows:

```
 public class EntityA {
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a") 
   private List<EntityB> bList;
 }

 public class EntityB {
   @ManyToOne
   private EntityA a;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "b")
   private List<EntityC> cList; 
 }

 public class EntityC {
   @ManyToOne
   private EntityB b;
 }
```

So you have a specific `EntityA` that you want to fetch it's associated `EntityB` instances.  You can obtain that list either at query time or as a post initialization step.

The important thing to note here is that the mappings between A - B - C are using `@OneToMany` which are lazily fetched by default.

To do this at query time:

```
SELECT a
  FROM EntityA a
  JOIN FETCH EntityB b
 WHERE a.id = :entityAId
```

The returned `EntityA` already has your `List<EntityB>` already loaded for you and you need to do nothing else.

To do this as a post initialization step after you've fetched a single `EntityA` instance.

```
Hibernate.initialize(entityA.getBList());

or

entityA.getBList().size();
```

Comment: thats exactly what i am doing as i explained on my post, but the thing is that as i also mentioned on the post this solution throws an exception because of List<C> of each object of class B and does not work

Comment: Update your post with the exception then so I can adjust my answer accordingly.  I suspect you may be doing the `initialize` after your session has been closed :).

Comment: no, that's not the problem. The problem is that when you do the initialize it brings all the objects inside the object b if you have eager and if you have lazy, that is what i have and want, it throws an exception. The exception is the following: 

HTTP Status 500 - Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: ar.com.anovo.business.A["b"]->ar.com.anovo.business.B_$$_jvst767_1e["c"]->ar.com.anovo.business.C_$$_jvst767_6["code"]);

If i do this:

Hibernate.initialize(a.getB().getC());

Comment: If i do this:
Hibernate.initialize(a.getB().getC());
It works but the thing is that in this case i  only want object B without bringing c from data base.